# Let $L$ the language over $\{a,b\}$ of words that contains the same number of occurrences of $a$ and $b$. Which of the following languages is regular?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

The options are:

(a) $L \cap a^{\ast}b^{\ast}$

(b) $(L \cap a^{\ast}b^{\ast}) \cup a^{\ast}b^{\ast}$

(c) $L \cup a^{\ast}b^{\ast}$

(d) $(L \cap a^{\ast}b^{\ast}) \cup b^{\ast}a^{\ast}$

My doubt is: We don't know what exactly $L$ is, it could be $a^{n}b^{n}$ or $b^{n}a^{n}$, we for sure know that $L$ is either of the two!

The way I think is, when we look at the first option the resultant language can be either $\epsilon$ or $a^{n}b^{n}$ because $L$ can be either of the mentioned choices, which also means that we can't deduce it properly, similarly i cannot decipher the other options.

Can someone explain why each option is either correct or wrong choice? Given that the correct option is $(b)$

Comment: "We don't know what exactly L is, it could be $a^nb^n$ or $b^na^n$, we for sure know that L is either of the two!" > I don't understand this sentence. $a^nb^n$ and $b^na^n$ are words, not languages. And even if you meant $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geqslant 0\}$, this is not equal to $L$. $L$ contains all words with the same number of $a$'s and $b$'s, like $a^nb^n$ for any $n$, but also $b^na^n$, but also $abababab…$, but also $aabbbbaa$, …

Comment: @Nathaniel Oh that's true! I did think of that but somehow convinced myself otherwise but now that you have re-stated it in a clear format, i agree $L$ can be any of the langauges you mentioned. And yes i meant langauges as you said! Do you know how to further deduce the solution?

Answer (score 1):

(b) is the only correct answer and this follows directly from the well known proof, $L_1 = \{a^n b^n : n \in \mathbf{N}\}$ is not regular. You can refer to the second page of [this](https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/%7Enick/cscB36/additional-notes/pumping.pdf) resource, for example.

---

(a) We start of by noting that $L' = L \cap a^*b^*$ is equivalent to $L_1$, which is not regular.

(b) $L_1 \cup a^*b^*$ is equivalent to $a^*b^*$ which is regular. This can be easily verified by constructing a single state automaton accepting any number of $a$s and $b$s.

(c) We prove this using pumping lemma. Let
$x = b^na^n$. Clearly, $x \in L', |x| \geq n$.
Let $uv = b^j$ for some $j \in \mathbf{N}, 0 \leq j \leq n, v = b^k$ for some $k \in \mathbf{N}, 0 < k \leq n$.
If $L'$ was regular, then $uv^2w = b^{n+k}a^n \in L'$, which is not true. Thus, $L'$ is not regular.

(d) Here, $L' = a^nb^n \cup b^*a^*$. Apply the same proof as in (c) for the string $x = a^kb^k, k \in \mathbf{N}$.